# To Do Application involving React Native

Tags: react-native, checkbox, styles, react-native-flatlist

Main objective is creating a todo app with a FlatList and CheckBox. CheckBox must have a line pass through once the object has been clicked or pressed. I need help putting in the checkbox within the  FlatList and also the action of the checkbox as well with the line passing through once clicked.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
 
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';

import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';


export default function App() {

const [car, setCar] = useState(false);

const [tree, setTree] = useState(false);

const [boxing, setBoxing] = useState(false);

const tasks = []

const click = () => {
   
if (car === true) {
  
tasks.push("car")
}

if (tree === true) {
  
tasks.push("tree")

}

if (boxing === true) 
{
  
tasks.push("boxing")
  
 }
   
Alert.alert("Tasks have been completed")
 
}

return <View style={StyleSheet.container}>

<CheckBox title={<Text style={{ textDecorationLine: "line-through" }}>"Change car oil"</Text>} checked={car} onPress={() => setCar(!car)} />
<CheckBox title={<Text style={{ textDecorationLine: "line-through" }}>"Cut tree"</Text>} checked={tree} onPress={() => setTree(!tree)} />
<CheckBox title={<Text style={{ textDecorationLine: "line-through" }}>"Go boxing"</Text>} checked={boxing} onPress={() => setBoxing(!boxing)} />
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Flatlist's docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)? I would encourage you to try to use it before asking how to use it. We can take a look at your code if it didn't work, no problem.

About the code you posted, have you thought about using only one state? It could be an array like this:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
```

inside you can set the strings of the activated checkboxes, something like:

```
const check = (checkedTask) => {
    setTasks(prev => {
        if (prev.find(task => task === checkedTask) {
            return prev.filter(task => task !== checkedTask)
        }
    return [...prev, checkedTask]
  })
}
```